# useLayoutEffect does not update UI before react dom paints UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

I was practicing useRef usage with useEffect hook. Simply, it shows the old value since useEffect hook runs after React paints the UI.

```
function UseRefExample1() {
const ref = useRef('')
const [val, setVal] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = val
}, [val])

return (
    <div className='Home'>
        
        <input type='text' value={val} onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)}/>
       <p>my current value - {val} - my old value - {ref.current}</p>
       
    </div>
)
 }

export default UseRefExample1
```

I wanted to test the same code with useLayoutEffect since it fires synchronously after all DOM mutations and right before React paints the UI. And, I expected to see current value placeholder and old value placeholder same, but the output is not different from useEffect hook usage.

```
function UseRefExample2() {
const ref = useRef('')
const [val, setVal] = useState('')

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current = val
}, [val])

return (
    <div className='Home'>
        
        <input type='text' value={val} onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)}/>
       <p>my current value - {val} - my old value - {ref.current}</p>
       
    </div>
   )
}

export default UseRefExample2
```

If someone can explain the reason why useLayoutEffect hook does not make current value and old value same, I would be thankful.

Comment: What would you expect this output to be? `let val = 1, ref = { current: val }; setTimeout(() => { ref.current++; }, 1); console.log(val, ref.current);` If you guessed `1 2` you'd be wrong.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I understand your point, but what I dont understand is behavior of useLayoutEffect. I expected that after a key stroke, value is updated, component rerenders but before ui updates uselayouteffect hooks runs its code and browser shows ref.current same as val. Otherwise, I understand how useEffect runs.

Comment: "useLayoutEffect since ... and right before React paints the UI" > Not really. For what I understood, useLayoutEffect is sync and will wait for all React Dom renders, then execute "before *Browser* painting".
Fact is, all components have already been rendered by React, the difference between your state and your ref will be visible.
a/ You update your state from 0 to 1
b/ React renders the comp with 1 and 0
c/ useLayoutEffect waits for all React renders (1 and 0 are rendered)
d/ useLayoutEffect update ref to 1
e/ Browser paint the Dom (1 and 0) (as after c)